# How to two geometries or meshes are merge in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I using 2 geometry, one is line based square 2D geometry, the second is icon image. I expect Should center and place the icons inside the 2d rectangle drawn region area. Below my code.

```
var combined = new THREE.Geometry(); 
        var squareGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
        squareGeometry.vertices.push(
                new THREE.Vector3(startX, startY, 0),
                new THREE.Vector3(endX, startY, 0),
                new THREE.Vector3(endX, endY, 0),
                new THREE.Vector3(startX, endY, 0),
                new THREE.Vector3(startX, startY, 0)
                );

        var square = new THREE.Line(squareGeometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
            color: color
        }));

        var iconGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(objSize.width, objSize.height);
        var iconMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({        map:THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('images/plantIcon.png')
         });
        var icon = new THREE.Mesh(iconGeometry,iconMaterial);
        icon.position.x = objPosition.x;
        icon.position.y = objPosition.z;

        combined.merge(square.geometry, square.matrix);
        combined.merge(icon.geometry, icon.matrix);
         var display = new THREE.Line(combined, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color: color,
        }));

        scene.add(display);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. this link have Merging Geometry [link](http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/10/05/performance-merging-geometry/)

Comment: I tried this link merging geometry but not visible properly simple image and square outline region. I used two mesh one is line based square diagram another sample image. anyway thank you.@vishnuajan

Comment: i think you need geometry group. it's link grouping objects